# iPhone SDK - drag only 1 thing at a time

Tags: iphone, touch, multi-touch

This seems quite complicated to me, and I cannot get it to work.
Basically what I want to do, is I have created 9 objects on the screen, and I want to be able to drag all of them, but I only want to be able to drag one at a time.
Eg, drag item 1, stop dragging item 1. Drag item 3, stop dragging item 3. Drag item 2, stop dragging item 2.
I will put the 'VERY' simplified code below, but it will probably be pretty much useless, I just don't want to put all my code in, as it is very badly written at the moment, and doesn't make much sense.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

self.center = CGPointMake(pos.x+difference.x, pos.y+difference.y);

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set **exclusiveTouch** to YES for all 9 view objects. Then it will cause only one view to be touched at a time.

[See the reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)